# Angular application show cors issue and not redirecting to azure ad login page

Tags: angular, azure, spring-boot

I have create a spring boot + Angular application. I am using Azure Ad for authorization.
When I run spring boot application and test it with swagger, it automatically redirect to Microsoft Loging page and ask me for creds and api works fine.
But when I use angular to hit that api.. it shows cors error.
When I remove all properties of Azure AD from my spring app..Angular project works fine (no cors issue).

---

Here is my application.properties

```
server.port=9090
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:xxxxxx/xxxxxxx
spring.datasource.username=xxxxxxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxxxxx
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true



############### Azure Properties ##################
spring.security.user.name=seligent
spring.security.user.password=seligent

azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=51d1f24c-6xxxxxxxxxxx82e712c0cb
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-id=9f7148a8-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-909ab498ddc8
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-secret=~Ffh7qg5E-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy346k23

azure.activedirectory.user-group.allowed-groups=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

here is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.sk'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin:'base'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    
    //azure dependencies
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter:2.3.3'  
    
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

---

when I hit api with angular it shows cors error
[image]

If I remove all values of azure from spring it works fine.
Here is my webSecurityCOnfig

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .userInfoEndpoint()
            .oidcUserService(oidcUserService);
    }
}
```

### Here is MvcConfig

```
@Configuration
public class ScipMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST")
        .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
  }

  @Override
  public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
    UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
    urlPathHelper.setUrlDecode(false);
    configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the options in your angular application. Use this options to call the HTTP request

```
const options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    Authorization: 'Basic ',// your authorization method
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':
      'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  })
};

getPerson(name: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .get<any>(baseUrl + '/persons/' + name, options)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```